# PHP Codeigniter Do Upload Function Does Not Work

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

i want to use do_upload function codeigniter and i have tried to solving this code with any tutorial. Please help me to solve this problem.

in controller:

```
function simpan_berita(){
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if(!empty($_FILES['filefoto']['name']))
            {
                if ($this->upload->do_upload('filefoto'))
                {
                    $gbr = $this->upload->data();
                    //Compress Image
                    $config['image_library']='gd2';
                    $config['source_image']='./assets/images/'.$gbr['file_name'];
                    $config['create_thumb']= FALSE;
                    $config['maintain_ratio']= FALSE;
                    $config['quality']= '60%';
                    $config['width']= 840;
                    $config['height']= 450;
                    $config['new_image']= './assets/images/'.$gbr['file_name'];
                    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();

                    ...
                    echo $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','success');
                    redirect('user/berita');
                }else{
                    echo $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','warning');
                    redirect('user/berita');
                }

            }else{
                redirect('admin/berita');
            }
}
```

and this is my views code:

```
        <form action="<?php echo base_url().'user/berita/simpan_berita'?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          ...
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Gambar</label>
            <input type="file" name="filefoto" style="width: 100%;" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

When i try to upload, other else condition will be run:

```
            else{
                echo $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','warning');
                redirect('user/berita');
            }
```

i need do_upload condition will be run. Please comment to help. Thankyou..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind...

Either your `/assets/images/`directory is not accesible (wrong path and/or not writable by codeigniter), in which case you should double check the path and/or try changing permissions of the  directory to 777 and, if everything starts working, work your way down to a more reasonable permission level.

Or, this is another case (i've read many, but so far I still thought it was just a hoax) that CI's upload library doesn't seem to like it if you use anything other than `userfile` as the field name being uploaded. Try changing all references of `filefoto` to `userfile` in both the view and the controller and see if it magically starts to work :)

Comment: Yeah, this is what i want! i have change permissions of the directory to 777, and then boom! i see the magical with the references filefoto, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can display the errors by

`echo $this->upload->display_errors();`

Or just check

`$this->upload->error_msg;`